# PHP unit test - test method return generator

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I would like to write a unit test for method when internal MockClass will call method once and that will return Generator.

```
$em            = $this->createMock(EntityManagerInterface::class);
$builder       = $this->createMock(ArticleBuilder::class);
$massiveInsert = new MassiveInsert($em);

$builder->expects(($this->once()))->method('createMany')->willReturn(new \Generator());
$builder->expects(($this->exactly(3)))->method('create')->willReturn(Article::class);

$massiveInsert->insertMany($builder, ['test', 'test1', 'test2']);
```

So far I wrote something like this. But I have following error:

```
Error: The "Generator" class is reserved for internal use and cannot be manually instantiated
```

So how to check if method "createMany" was called once and return generator?

Thank you.

Builder method:

```
public function create(
        string $title
    ): Article {
        return new Article($title);
    }

    
    public function createMany(array $data): Generator
    {
        foreach ($data['title'] as $title) {
            yield $this->create($title);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide what `::createMany()` actually does. Also I get a feeling you're misunderstanding what `::willReturn()` actually does. In mocking the `::create()` method, which I'm guessing will return an object, you're passing the class name, `Article::class`, as though `::willReturn()` will instantiate it. Either pass an object, or an anonymous function that will instantiate a class and return the created object.

Comment: @loydg I edited my question adding builder class.